# Requests timeout when sent from webservices after upgrade to play 2.3.8

Tags: web-services, playframework, cxf, playframework-2.3

So here's the story, I've got a play framework application that uses org.apache.cxf plugin to provide SOAP services. In my routes file, I have the following:

```
GET     /soap/*path                 org.apache.cxf.transport.play.CxfController.handle(path)
POST    /soap/*path                 org.apache.cxf.transport.play.CxfController.handle(path)
```

This routes to one of my own functions that turns the path into another request that will hit my usual controllers. We do this by building up on a `WSRequestHolder` object. We set headers, query parameters, etc.

This used to work quite well in play 2.2 but with the upgrade to 2.3.8, there seems to be an issue. I've traced it to this line:

```
Promise<WSResponse> responsePromise =  request.get();    
WSResponse response = responsePromise.get(2000);
```

When we make the request (when calling response.Promise.get) the call times out regardless of the timeout set. I was testing with a basic login request and it used to respond in less that 200 ms. I've reproduced the request parameters using postman and the request seems to work fine on it's own but when it's being fired from my webservice, it times out.

I maybe have missed something in the upgrade to 2.2 but I'm not even sure what to debug. It clearly doesn't hit the controller, and turning on play logs at the DEBUG level doesn't even see the request.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

I have tested it in dev and prod mode. Both seem to fail in the same place.

Comment: Is this in dev mode? Play processes requests serially in dev mode, so if you're making a WS call to your own app and blocking, I'm pretty sure it will be doomed to timeout.

Comment: Interesting, it is in dev mode... Also, this worked in play 2.2 so it would have been nice if this was mentioned in the migration guide. I wonder if there is a way to bypass that restriction without switching to prod mode (which also disables auto-reloading)

Comment: Also, switching to application.mode=prod still shows the problem.

Comment: unless i still don't know how to set application to prod... I thought putting application.mode=prod into the application.conf file would do it, but the logs still say that play is launching in dev mode.

Comment: `activator start` It would be interesting to see how it behaves there.

Comment: Can't even run `activator start`, complains about `The input line is too long.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

Comment: Ah, maybe i should read the docs first. I guess I need a few things first. Blast.

Comment: Even fully packaged and deployed (as much production mode as I can imagine) it still doesn't work. It looks like the SOAP request times out still. Can't tell for sure because of the lack of deugging.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The issue was that, during our redirection of the request, we were re-adding the Content-Length header twice, once as the length and once as zero (in an attempt to force the regeneration of the length). Turns out this works in play 2.2 but causes it to hang in 2.3. Making sure to only add the Content-Length header once prevents the request from hanging. Dev/Prod mode tested and working.